# On SBS2003: Unable to access OMA, receiving 1503 and 3005 Events

Tags: exchange, windows-sbs-2003, iphone

On my SBS 2003 Server, I've been trying to access OMA unsuccessfully all day.  When I first checked, the OMA mapping was missing, so I recreated the Vdirs per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883380.

At this point, OMA was returning "A System error has occurred while processing your request. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact your administrator."

I then took the following steps, all to no avail.

I tried creating entries for the server's NetBIOS name on all of its IP addresses per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/898131

I tried adding an SMTPProxy entry per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319681.

Someone mentioned that modifying the homeMTA information was incorrect and recommended updating it manually per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319886

I also reinstalled ASP.NET 1.1, and when all else failed, I rebooted the server.

Attempts to access /OMA via the NetBIOS name, the FQDN, and localhost all generate Event ID 1503 (MSExchangeOMA) with a (501) Not Implemented error.  Attempts to connect a mobile device (I've tried a WinMo phone and an iPhone) have generated Event ID 3005.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With SBS 2003 and issues like this your first action should be to run the Internet Connection Wizard from the management console. There's a tick box on one of the screens to allow mobile access. If and only if this fails should you try and manually modify the IIS config. SBS is quite a complex beast and attempts to make changes manually frequently cause pain.

John Rennie

Comment: I completely agree, and normally would have done the same thing, unfortunately, decisions made prior to my arrival make running the wizard a bit more of a challenge as all of the configuration was done by hand.  I understand the initial logic, as all of the wizards in SBS can be a bit heavy handed, and I think this may be a different issue that the connectivity wizard wouldn't  be able to resolve.  Wiping out their RRAS configuration isn't an option, however.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfgame-

John is right... you are setting yourself up for a world of pain by trying to manually setup OMA on SBS, and his suggestion to re-run the Internet Connection Wizard is a good one.

The first question I would have for you however is "Did this ever work"?  I can't tell from your post if it used to work and just stopped, or if you are trying to set it up for the first time and are hitting the problems that you are.  If it used to work, what changed between then and now?

-Sean

Comment: It was working before, and according to the event logs, failed on 2/28.  I should clarify that this isn't an environment that I've been supporting until recently.  I've just started working on it for a firm that subcontracts out to me for IT consulting.

Running  the wizards could potentially be problematic, as the people who setup the server in the first place didn't, and made some changes to RRAS that would be wiped out by the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, given that you've stated that your SBS configuration wizards don't work and that many settings have been changed outside of the standard configuration framework, you are now essentially in a disaster recovery situation. I would recommend the following courses of action:

1. Stop thrashing! Don't change any more settings, you will only sink faster. SBS is a finely balanced system of potentially conflicting technology. Straying outside of Microsoft's configuration scenarios - as you have discovered - is a fast way to trip over the unexpected subtleties and it should never be configured other than by the supported consoles and utilities.
2. Download and run the SBS Best Practices Analyzer and take stock of your situation.
3. Consider recovering this server by performing a "[swing migration](http://www.sbsmigration.com)". You can swing your active directory and user data off onto a temporary host (which can be a virtual machine), reinstall a clean copy of SBS2003, then swing your active directory and files back from the temporary host. This will give you a clean, working SBS installation which you can then manage using the provided consoles. I have used this technique several times myself and it can be a real life-saver.

Alternatively, locate a qualified Microsoft Small Business Specialist or SBS MVP in your area and seek their advice.